# How do I dodge and grab?

Tags: ios, infinity-blade

Does anyone know how to dodge the elbow hit and grab with the hand(usually with the trolls)? Nothing works for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are some attacks that you can't dodge. You should be able to block those attacks, though.